# Remove everything expect src in Image Tag using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove everything expect `src` in `Image` tag using `regex`.
I am using C# but I don't want to use `HTMLAgilityPack` I want it using regex only.
How to get this ?
If `String` is `<img id="image" class="header" src="test.png">` then it returns as `<img src="test.png">`
Image tag may contain many other extra properties.

Comment: "I don't want to use HTMLAgilityPack I want it using regex only."  You really should explain why you don't want to use what is normally the correct tool for the job.  Otherwise, you are asking us to solve something that a perfectly good library has already solved, for no apparent reason.

Comment: @dan1111 Normally, I'd agree with you. However, this isn't really matching over a whole HTML page, but only inside a single node that's already been extracted. In addition, all that needs matching is the `src="test.png"`, because you can simply put that in a new HTML tag. This is a VERY simple match: `"(src=\".*\")"`. If he doesn't need HTMLAgilityPack for anything else, just to match this single tag, I think it would be overkill to add it just for this single extraction from a single node. However, if he needs to do more, I agree that he should go for the established solution.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Unless the src tag isn't the last tag. Or used single quotes.

Comment: `(src=['\"].+['\"])` works with both single and double quotes. And my regex already didn't care where the src tag was located.

Comment: correction: it did care about it. Just make it non-greedy: `(src=['\"].+?['\"])`

Comment: @NateKerkhofs, I don't want to remove src. I want to remove everything expect src. check : http://regex101.com/r/wT6lL3/1

Comment: @CSAT You misunderstand: you don't REMOVE src with that, you extract it from the current string and paste it into a new string. I'll add an answer to clarify.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs, ohkk... Isn't there anyway to remove everything expect src ???

Comment: @CSAT While you could construct a monster of a regex to do that it's just not feasible. It's FAR easier (both to program and to understand) if you simply extract just that single thing you need and paste it into a new string. you don't know how many tags there are in the img tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my comments: Normally I wouldn't recommend parsing HTML Using Regex. however, this is one of the few times when it's possible without ending up with a disastrously complicated regex string, because here you have a single node, with 1 pair of matching angle brackets. In addition, the OP only needs a single tag from this string. If he needed to do anything more complicated, I'd agree that he should use HTMLAgilityPack, but this is perfectly doable.

What you do is you extract the tag from the string using this regex: `(src=['\"].+?['\"])`. Then you take what you extracted from the string and paste it into a new string:

```
String newImgTag = String.Format("<img {0}>", srcMatch);
```

Again, if this were any more complicated (or if I had to do other HTML manipulation), I would just skip the regex and go for the established solutions like the aforementioned HTMLAgilityPack, because it offers far more support for HTML manipulation.

However, I don't view this as HTML manipulation, because you got a single tag without even a matching closing tag. This is more like basic string manipulation. It's similar to calculating a number to the second power: I doubt anyone would import the entire math library just for that, they'd just do N * N.

I fully expect and accept that people will downvote me for even considering to use Regex for this. Before you do so, however, read the post and think about it. This is one of those borderline cases where HTMLAgilityPack would make the project far more complicated without actually adding anything except that you're not using Regex. Regex has its uses, it's only when you abuse it that it becomes a monster to work with.

Comment: I'm still not convinced.  This could break in a variety of ways (src attribute in a script tag, broken content within comments, a page that shows HTML source code, etc.) Maybe it will work on the OP's input data, but then again, *maybe not*.  We don't know enough about the task--which is why I asked for clarification. I am not categorically opposed to using regexes on HTML. Some tasks call for a quick-and-dirty approach.  But without more information, it is not clear this is appropriate. Most people who ask questions like this really should use a parser.

Comment: @dan1111 I agree with your comment. However, all I had that I could base my answer on was that example string. Based on what the OP said (a string containing a single image tag with an src attribute and any number of other attributes), a simple Regex is good enough for this. It's not like he's asking to process an entire DOM element tree using Regex. He also could have a legitimate reason for not usin a parser. He could be in a closed environment with the "not invented here" syndrome. He could be working on a very small project  where a parser would dramatically increase the project size.